# Wrong behavior after rotation transform in Swift 4

Tags: swift, rotation, transform

This is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var btnOutlet: UIButton!
var degree = 0
var location = CGPoint(x: 112, y: 308)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func moveAndSnap(_ sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .began || sender.state == .changed {
        let translation = sender.translation(in: sender.view)

        switch degree {
        case 0:
            let changeX = (sender.view?.center.x)! + translation.x
            let changeY = (sender.view?.center.y)! + translation.y
            sender.view?.center = CGPoint(x: changeX, y: changeY)
            sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: sender.view)

        case 180:
            let changeX = (sender.view?.center.x)! - translation.x
            let changeY = (sender.view?.center.y)! - translation.y
            sender.view?.center = CGPoint(x: changeX, y: changeY)
            sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: sender.view)

        case 360:
            let changeX = (sender.view?.center.x)! + translation.x
            let changeY = (sender.view?.center.y)! + translation.y
            sender.view?.center = CGPoint(x: changeX, y: changeY)
            sender.setTranslation(CGPoint.zero, in: sender.view)

        default:
            break
        }
    }

    if sender.state == .ended {
        if 90 ... 140 ~= Int((sender.view?.frame.origin.x)!) && 285 ... 330 ~= Int((sender.view?.frame.origin.y)!) {
            sender.view?.frame.origin = location
        }

        // PROBLEM starts here. Explanation is under this code
        if btnOutlet.frame.origin == location {
            if degree == 0 || degree == 360 {
                print("Hurra!")
            }
        } else {
            print(degree)
            print(btnOutlet.frame.origin)
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func rotate(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if degree == 360 {
        degree = 180
    } else {
        degree += 180
    }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        self.btnOutlet.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(Double.pi/(180/Double(self.degree))))
    }
}
```

PROBLEM:
Everytime I rotate my btnOutlet to 360 degree and move its frame to location, this code below doesn't work. Why?
The funny thing is, that when I ask in 'else' below, the outprint is location. What do I wrong?

```
        if btnOutlet.frame.origin == location {
            if degree == 0 || degree == 360 {
                print("Hurra!")
            }
        } else {
            print(btnOutlet.frame.origin)
            print(location)
        }
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you started working with transform, it is always a good practice to be consistent and continue working with transforms. Just keep in mind order of transformations. Perhaps you a looking for smoothing similar to:

```
@IBAction func panRecognised(_ gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.state == .began || gesture.state == .changed{
        guard let targetView = gesture.view else { return }
        let transform =  targetView.transform
        let translation = gesture.translation(in: view)
        targetView.transform = transform.concatenating(CGAffineTransform(translationX: translation.x, y: translation.y))
        gesture.setTranslation(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), in: view)
    }
}
```

Comment: First, I thank you very much for your answer.
But I didn't get your idea or what you want to tell me to change/use in my code...
Could you please explain it more deeper?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Now I tried everything to implement your code into mine. With your code I only can trim my code at the point "switch degree" but, like before, if I rotate my btnOutlet to 360 and check if its frame.origin is at location, it doesn't recognize it. What should I do?

Comment: Ok. Maybe I misunderstood you in the first place. What view you are trying to move? PS: possible reason of problem in your if so that origin is float, and can vary from expected value. Maybe replacing **btnOutlet.frame.origin == location** by **abs(btnOutlet.frame.origin.x - location.x) < 1 && abs(btnOutlet.frame.origin.y - location.y) < 1** will help

Comment: Ok now with this **abs(btnOutlet.frame.origin.x - location.x) < 1 && abs(btnOutlet.frame.origin.y - location.y) < 1** it works perfect!!! Man you don't know how much you helped me out! I thank you very much! Even if I don't know what the **abs** means and why my code didn't work... **THANK YOU**